# Wierd bug in CodeIgniter when I queried two tables with relationship... o_O

Tags: codeigniter, relational-database

So I got a wierd bug (or maybe I'm just stupid), when I runs an active record query. Take a look at this:

```
$results = $this->db->
  select('cd.casino_name, cd.casino_opened, cd.casino_latitude, cd.casino_longitude')->
  from('casino_data as cd, casino_cities as cc')->
  where('cd.city_id',$city_id)->
  where('cd.city_id=cc.city_id')->
  get()->result_array();
```

Then I got that:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'cd.city_id=cc.city_id' in 'where clause'

SELECT `cd`.`casino_name`, `cd`.`casino_opened`, `cd`.`casino_latitude`, `cd`.`casino_longitude`
FROM (`m_casino_data` as cd, `m_casino_cities` as cc)
WHERE `cd`.`city_id` =  1
AND `cd`.`city_id=cc`.`city_id`

Filename: httpdocs/_dev/libraries/Test.php

Line Number: 649
```

Sh*t happened... Or in v2.0 CI has been changed something in the DB class?

help plz...thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there with the where clause

```
$results = $this->db->
select('cd.casino_name, cd.casino_opened, cd.casino_latitude, cd.casino_longitude')->
from('casino_data as cd, casino_cities as cc')->
where('cd.city_id',$city_id)->
where('cd.city_id','cc.city_id')->//this would produce WHERE cd.city_id = cc.city_id
get()->result_array();
```

Comment: OMFG it works with `where('cd.city_id = cc.city_id')` I just added a space before and after the =

thx anyway

Comment: well thats something that need to be filed as a bug. Let me check the Library. :)

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter's AR protecting works poorly sometimes. In this cases I think you should use an optional parameter `FALSE` to avoid autoprotecting. But not all function accepts this parameter - but `where` yes!

> `$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

See [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) (you can find near `4. Custom string`).